# How do I get the sum of multiple columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner to Python and data structures. How would I be able to find the sum of the values in specific columns for the rows I want? For example, say I wanted to find all the sum of the values of 2018 hiv diagnoses + 2018 aids diagnoses + 2019 hiv diagnoses + 2019 aids diagnoses + 2017 hiv diagnoses + 2017 aids diagnoses for The Bronx

I have the csv file saved as a dataframe called diagnoses. I know that to select columns that are next to each other, I can use iloc. But in this case I am skipping the 2017,2018,2019 deaths columns.

Thanks in advance.

| Borough | 2018 hiv diagnoses | 2018 aids diagnoses | 2018 deaths | 2019 hiv diagnoses | 2019 aids diagnoses | 2017 hiv diagnoses | 2017 aids diagnoses | 2017 deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bronx | 2 | 4 | 54 | 23 | 98 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 0 |
| Bronx | 6 | 9 | 5 | 76 | 45 | 9 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| Bronx | 2 | 4 | 54 | 23 | 98 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 0 |
| Manhattan | 6 | 9 | 5 | 76 | 45 | 9 | 6 | 4 | 3 |

Edit: My code so far and expected output.

All I really have is importing the csv as a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 

diagnoses = pd.read_csv('DATA\\HIV_AIDS.csv')
print("HIV/AIDS Diagnoses and Deaths from 2017-19 \n")
print(diagnoses_csv)
print()
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
bronx_diagnoses = ...
print("Total diagnoses in the Bronx 2017-2019: ", bronx_diagnoses)

brooklyn_diagnoses = ...
print("Total diagnoses in Brooklyn 2017-2019: ", brooklyn_diagnoses)
```

Total diagnoses in the Bronx 2017-2019: (insert sum)

Total diagnoses in the Brooklyn 2017-2019: (insert sum)

Comment: Provide the code that you have been working on.

Comment: If you can't use `.iloc`, then use `.loc` here and select the columns you need or simply `df[['col1', 'col1', 'col3'..]]`

Comment: for your current data just simply use: `df['sum']=df.sum(1)`

Comment: kindly provide the expected output

Comment: Updated with some code and expected output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are fancier ways, but [**`.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) works. Specify rows with a boolean index and columns as a list:

```py
rows = df.Borough == 'Bronx'
columns = ['2018 hiv diagnoses', '2018 aids diagnoses', '2019 hiv diagnoses', '2019 aids diagnoses', '2017 hiv diagnoses', '2017 aids diagnoses']

bronx_diagnoses = df.loc[rows, columns].sum().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pandas dataframe (data), you can subset for specific columns by enclosing the column names in a list.

Then you can the use the `sum()` method to compute the column sums, and then sum again to get the total amount.

```
data[[
    '2018 hiv diagnoses', '2018 aids diagnoses',
    '2019 hiv diagnoses', '2019 aids diagnoses',
    '2017 hiv diagnoses', '2017 aids diagnoses'
    ]].sum().sum()
```

Comment: This was great, thank you! My mistake I forgot to add in my post I wanted to find the sum for The Bronx. How would I include the row?